# body doesn't end with the end of the div

Tags: html

I'm in a little bit of a pickle. My page doesn't end with my footer, as it would normally do. Instead, there is a lot of "body background" going on after all my divs end, while I would really like the scroll to end with the bottom of the footer.

I am not entirely sure, but this effect may have to do with my page menu, which uses text and jpg with a lot of hover (on the active page it has a height of 350px, on Dreamweaver's layout however it is about triple that height, due to all the jpgs which are listed.

My question: Is there a way to make the page "end" with the last div, the footer? As the whole html is a little too much, here's my basic layout:

```
<body>
<div class="backgroundofwholepage">

  <div class="menu">
  <!--contains a few other divs for the menu-->
  </div>

  <div class="content">
  <!--contains a three column div structure, based on float-->
  <br class="clearfloat">
  <!--contains clear:both-->
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
```

If any of you have an idea, I'd much appreciate your help!

ACME

Comment: Regarding class names like "fltright" and "clearfloat", I encourage you to read http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#semanticselector

Answer (score 1):

You either want a [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) (putting your footer at the bottom of the page for sure) or you want to put a background on your html element so that the body background doesn't fill the window.

```
html { background:white }
body { background-image:url( ... ) }
```

For example, see: http://jsfiddle.net/vRBZM/

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer Phrogz! Interesting turnout (never would have thought of that on my own...): I changed the html background to plain white and it looks as if the body ends with the div but the html just goes on for another screen-height or so. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Acme You must have some very large padding for that to be the case. Please post a pared-down test case showing the problem, preferably at a place like http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Ok, I uploaded the basic layout here: http://jsfiddle.net/2LRj7/2/ The error seems to occur here already, even without jpgs.

Comment: @Acme Respectfully, it would be helpful if you would pare that down. That is not a pared-down test case, and as such that puts more burden on people wanting to help. Delete any HTML and CSS that does not contribute to the problem. Rinse/repeat until it's really pared down. Either you'll find your problem in the process, or you'll have a simple repro case that people can understand and help with quickly.

Comment: @Phrogz I understand of course and I am very sorry for the inconvenience. I broke it down the most I could - I got as far as to suspect it is the menus fault. However, if I start taking out bits and pieces of the menu, the whole thing doesn't work anymore. (It is looking a bit wild, I give you that, but I really have no idea what to look for - I just cannot seem to see the connection to the body/html part.) I took out all the comments now, but left whatever I thought might be connected to the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/2LRj7/3/

Comment: @Acme I did more of your job for you and have pared it down to this: http://jsfiddle.net/2LRj7/4/ Keep working on that. Try deleting an entire subsection. See if that does it.